# Acceleration setInterval in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas

I am trying to create a bouncing ball (on a canvas). I would love if the ball could accelerate when going up and down. No idea how to do this with setInterval. Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (movement1 === true) {
        dotHeight += 1;
        if (dotHeight >= 100) movement1 = false;
    } else {
        dotHeight -= 1;
        if (dotHeight <= 0) movement1 = true;
    }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, (canvas.height / 2) + dotHeight, dotSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fill();
    }, 4);
```

This results in a linear movement. I would love to have a natural movement. Basically starting fast and getting slower when reaching the top and vice versa.

Comment: Hmm.. I would suggest that instead of decreasing the interval, rather increase the value that is added/reduced each time the interval runs. For example, if your item moves 10 pixels every second, you would increase it to 15 pixels per second instead of changing the interval to half a second.

Comment: makes sense. Seems to be the easiest solution! I will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have both a `speed` and a `gravity` (or `acceleration`) variable:

- `speed` tells you how many units (pixels here) is going to travel your object in **the current update**.
- `gravity` tells you by how many units is `speed` increased on **each update**.

You want a constant `gravity` so that `speed` is increasing the same amount of pixels on each update. That will give you a variable `speed`, so that your object (dot here) is travelling longer or shorter distances on each update, depending on the direction it is travelling.

To make the dot bounce just change the direction of its `speed` once it reaches the floor. You just need to multiply it by `-1` or, instead of that, you could multiply it by a `bouncingFactor` (`-1 < bouncingFactor < 0`) so that it loses energy on each bounce:

[image]

Here you can see a working example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var frames = 0; // Frame counter just to make sure you don't crash your browser while editing code!

// DOT STUFF:

var dotSize = 20;
var dotMinY = 0 + dotSize; // Start position
var dotMaxY = canvas.height - dotSize; // Floor
var dotY = dotMinY;
var dotSpeed = 0;
var dotLastBounceSpeed = 0; // You can use this to determine whether the ball is still bouncing enough to be visible by the user.

var center = canvas.width / 2; // Try to take every operation you can out of the animate function.
var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI;

// WORLD STUFF:

var gravity = .5;
var bounceFactor = .8; // If < 1, bouncing absorbs energy so ball won't go as high as it was before.

// MAIN ANIMATION LOOP:

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(center, dotY, dotSize, 0, pi2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();

  // First, dotSpeed += gravity is calculated and that returns the new value for dotSpeed
  // then, that new value is added to dotY.
  dotY += dotSpeed += gravity; 
  
  if(dotY >= dotMaxY ) {
    dotY = dotMaxY;
    dotSpeed *= -bounceFactor;  
  }

  var dotCurrentBounceSpeed = Math.round(dotSpeed * 100); // Takes two decimal digits.
  
  if(frames++ < 5000 && dotLastBounceSpeed != dotCurrentBounceSpeed) {
    dotLastBounceSpeed = dotCurrentBounceSpeed;
    setTimeout(animate, 16); // 1000/60 = 16.6666...
  }
  else alert("Animation end. Took " + frames + " frames.");
}

animate();
```

```css
html, body, #canvas {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

You should also consider using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) insted of `setTimeout`. From the MDN doc:

> The **Window.requestAnimationFrame()** method tells the browser that you
>   wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a
>   specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. The
>   method takes as an argument a callback to be invoked before the
>   repaint.

The same example with `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var frames = 0; // Frame counter just to make sure you don't crash your browser while editing code!

// DOT STUFF:

var dotSize = 20;
var dotMinY = 0 + dotSize; // Start position
var dotMaxY = canvas.height - dotSize; // Floor
var dotY = dotMinY;
var dotSpeed = 0;
var dotLastBounceSpeed = 0; // You can use this to determine whether the ball is still bouncing enough to be visible by the user.

var center = canvas.width / 2; // Try to take every operation you can out of the animate function.
var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI;

// WORLD STUFF:

var gravity = .5;
var bounceFactor = .8; // If < 1, bouncing absorbs energy so ball won't go as high as it was before.

// MAIN ANIMATION LOOP:

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(center, dotY, dotSize, 0, pi2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();

  // First, dotSpeed += gravity is calculated and that returns the new value for dotSpeed
  // then, that new value is added to dotY.
  dotY += dotSpeed += gravity; 
  
  if(dotY >= dotMaxY ) {
    dotY = dotMaxY;
    dotSpeed *= -bounceFactor;  
  }

  var dotCurrentBounceSpeed = Math.round(dotSpeed * 100); // Takes two decimal digits.
  
  if(frames++ < 5000 && dotLastBounceSpeed != dotCurrentBounceSpeed) {
    dotLastBounceSpeed = dotCurrentBounceSpeed;
    //setTimeout(animate, 10);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate); // Better!!
  }
  else alert("Animation end. Took " + frames + " frames.");
}

animate();
```

```css
html, body, #canvas {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

As you can see, you only need to change one line of code! However, you may need a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/Danziger/fc83f1b2f16f70655a4a) so that you fall back to `setTimeout` if the browser does not support `requestAnimationFrame`.

You can learn more about `requestAnimationFrame` in [this post](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/). It explains the basics and also how to set a custom frame rate.

Answer (score 2):

The basic principle is to use a velocity variable as opposed to a constant height increment. So instead of `dotHeight += 1` or `dotHeight -= 1` you would do `dotHeight += dotVelocity`, where you define dotVelocity, and subtract it by a constant value (gravity) whenever the ball is in the air.

```
var dotHeight = 0;
var dotVelocity = 3; // start out moving up, like in your example
var gravity = .1; // you can adjust this constant for stronger/weaker gravity

setInterval(function animate() {
ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

if (dotHeight > 0) { // if it hit the ground, stop movement
     dotVelocity -= gravity;
     dotHeight += dotVelocity;   
}
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, (canvas.height / 2) + dotHeight, dotSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fill();
}, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `speed` variable instead of the constant `1` to determine how "far" to move the ball, like this:

```
var speed = 1;

setInterval(function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (movement1 === true) {
        dotHeight += speed;
        if (dotHeight >= 100) movement1 = false;

        // make it faster
        speed += 1;
    } else {
        dotHeight -= speed;
        if (dotHeight <= 0) movement1 = true;

        // slow down
        speed -= 1;
    }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, (canvas.height / 2) + dotHeight, dotSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fill();
    }, 4);
```